# Random landscape layout issues

Tags: android, layout, landscape, landscape-portrait

I have build android application and in manifest I have `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` also I use  `android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"` I mention it just because maybe it can be related to my issue.

When I turn my phone to portrait and press home button to go to home screen and go back to my app in portrait it sometimes get displayed in portrait for a second and the it switches to landscape but this happens just very rarely.

Also I get random layout changes like you see in pictures. This all happens just like this I turn phone to portrait while my app is supposed to be landscape only based on my manifest definition.

My guess is that somehow android system is switching my app to portrait before recognizing it as landscape but I don't know how to fix it. I would like to to stay sensorlandscape too so I get it rotated for both landscape orientations. Maybe this is phone specific behaviour and some others don't do it (thats even worse then), hard to say app is not released yet...

On first picture you can see correct layout and others are how it gets randomly corrupted by having phone portrait and going to home and back to running app again...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I usually use Xamarin, so I'm unfamiliar with these mechanics. Have you tried using one of the app state change methods (for example onResume ()) to repaint the graphics when you reopen the application? See this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes

Comment: Well today I upgraded MIUI to new version 12 and the problem is "gone", MIUI is Xiaomi version of Android, so I can just expect this will happen to some users of my app without me to be able to fix it ever... without going back to MIUI 11 or experience it elsewhere... When I think about what you propose I see it as possibly causing more issues as some screen flik or something but we'll maybe my next step can be to abandon configchanges so layout will be restarted always it can be related but for now I wanted to stick with it..

Comment: Unfortunately, the various versions of Android are not new to this type of oddities. I hope you can find a satisfactory solution!